# Determine all $k$ such that $k^3+k+1$ is divisible by 11

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility, euclidean-algorithm

The task is the following:

Determine all $\ k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $k^3+k+1$ is divisible by 11

I assumed that "$k^3+k+1$ is divisible by 11" is saying $11|k^3+k+1$. That means I can rewrite it as a linear combination $$k^3+k+1 = 11n\quad\forall n\in\mathbb Z$$
I was thinking of factoring the polynomial on the left to make it easier to handle, but I don't think it's factorable. My guess is to use the Euclidean algorithm, but the polynomial on the left is making me uneasy.

Can someone show me how to proceed with this task?

Comment: Do you know anything about modular arithmetic?

Comment: I was thinking of that, but I'm not confident in my modular arithmetic skills.

Comment: That is the most natural method to use here. If you have two numbers $k_1$ and $k_2$ that are congruent modulo $11$, then the answer will be the same for both numbers. That is, $k^3 + k + 1$ will either be divisible by  $11$ for both $k=k_1$ and $k=k_2$ or for neither. Therefore if you can answer the question for $k=0,1,\dots,10$, you'll immediately have a complete answer. Or even $k=-5,-4,\dots,5$. That's because every integer $k$ is congruent to one of the numbers in the list.

Comment: You could write $k = 11t + r,$ with the understanding that $r$ is an integer with $0 \leq r \leq 10.$ Then you just check each such $r.$

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this faster by using modular arithmetic, but I won't use it:

Let $k=11t+r$ with $0\le r\le 10$. $$k^3+k+1=11\left(11^2t^3+3\cdot 11t^2\cdot r+3\cdot t\cdot r^2+t\right)+r^3+r+1$$

Therefore: $$11\mid k^3+k+1\iff 11\mid r^3+r+1$$

Now check cases $r=0,1,\ldots, 10$.

E.g., $11\nmid 0^3+0+1$ and $11\nmid 1^3+1+1$, but $11\mid 2^3+2+1$, etc.

You'll find that only $r=2$ works. Therefore, the answer is $k=11t+2$ for any $t\in\mathbb Z$.

If you could use modular arithmetic, you could solve this by checking cases $k\equiv 0,1,2,\ldots,10\pmod{11}$.

E.g., if $k\equiv 0\pmod{11}$, then $k^3+k+1\equiv 0^3+0+1\equiv 1\not\equiv 0\pmod{11}$, etc.

You would find that only $k\equiv 2\pmod{11}$ works.

---

Here's another solution. I could explain it without modular arithmetic, but I'll use it:

$$k^3+k+1\equiv k^3+k-10\equiv (k-2)\left(k^2+2k+5\right)\pmod{11}$$

By [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma):

$$\iff \left(k\equiv 2\pmod{11}\ \text{ or }\ k^2+2k+5\equiv 0\pmod{11}\right)$$

$$\iff \left(k\equiv 2\pmod{11}\ \text{ or }\ (k+1)^2\equiv 7\pmod{11}\right)$$

The second congruence has no solutions, because $7$ is not a quadratic residue mod $11$. This can be proved by checking $0^2, (\pm 1)^2, (\pm 2)^2,\ldots, (\pm 5)^2$ mod $11$ (none of these can be congruent to $7$ mod $11$), or by using [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity):

$$\left(\frac{7}{11}\right)=-\left(\frac{11}{7}\right)=-\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)=-\left(\frac{2^2}{7}\right)=-1$$